# azure media player show question mark in the closed caption while the vtt file doesn't have it

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

We have a video that is uploaded to Azure Media Service and being encoded, the video has a closed caption .vtt file, the problem is that the Azure Media Player is showing unwanted question mark like there is an unrecognized character there however when editing the vtt file it seems like everything is in good English, please check the following pictures and suggest what could be the reason for this behavior and what should I trie to solve it.

https://assaadf-paxosoft.tinytake.com/msc/ODk1MTIwNl8yMjQyNTY1Mw
https://assaadf-paxosoft.tinytake.com/msc/ODk1MTIwOV8yMjQyNTY3MA

Comment: Looks like a problem with recognizing the special characters in words/sentences. Check on that part, Some characters may not be recognized or rendered correctly in certain contexts. Ensure that the special characters are encoded properly in the file.